# Getting sales variation with lag function return 0

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, lag

I am trying to get the variation in % of the sales by using the `LAG` function from my CTE.

I've tried to do it manually ((actual-previous)/previous) * 100 and with the format function (as in my picture) but still get 0.00% as the variation % while it is clearly not that. Anyone as a clue why?

[image]

Comment: sample data would help ASylvestre. maybe dependy on your data the behaviour makes sense

Comment: sorry, i've updated the post with a picture of my result

Comment: Add your numerator and denominator to your SQL output. Break each part of your formula down until you see where the issue is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Still don't have the data so couldn't test but I would try something like this:

```
select mois, cmd, lag, Format(1.0*(cmd-lag)/lag,'P') as 'lag_%'
from cte_a
order by mois
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL has a tendency of rounding off the results if its not in the float format. For example:

```
select FORMAT((291-273)/273,'P')
```

The above statement returns 0%. Once you cast the numerator and denominator as float:

```
select FORMAT(CAST((291-273) as float)/CAST(273 as float),'P')
```

The above statement returns 6.59%. Perhaps you could give this a try.